# How do I prevent flickering on CTreeCtrl?

Tags: c++, c, windows, user-interface, mfc

I am using VS2010 to develop a MFC project. When I clicked on an item of a CTreeCtrl control, It's so strange that some other unrelated items flickers sometimes. I tried many computers, and this problem still exists. Any solutions?

This is a BCGControlBar project, the CTreeCtrl is linked with a CWorkSpaceBar2 class (Like the workspace bar in VS). I think this is not the point, because many other pure CTreeList demos also share the same flicker problem. A demo is provided below, you can find the flicker problem when you click an CTreeCtrl item. Although it is not my code, but we share the same problem.

http://www.verysource.com/testmytreectrl-59412.html

Below is some pieces of my code. You can find that I didn't do something strange that maybe cause the problem.

**initIcons()** function is for initializing icons for the items.

**add2Tree(CTreeCtrl* pTree, AFDir* pDir, HTREEITEM hItemParent, bool bHead)** function is for adding items.

**OnSelchanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)** function does nothing when an item is clicked.

```
void CWorkSpaceBar2::initIcons()
{
//  SHFILEINFO sfi;
//  SHGetFileInfo(m_strDataDir, 0, &sfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO),  SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
//  m_iIconFolder = sfi.iIcon;
// 
//  SHFILEINFO sfi2;
//  SHGetFileInfo(m_strDataDir + _T("coloring_rules.txt"), 0, &sfi2, sizeof(SHFILEINFO),  SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
//  m_iIconScript = sfi2.iIcon;
// 
//  SHFILEINFO sfi3;
//  SHGetFileInfo(m_strDataDir + _T("color2.ini"), 0, &sfi3, sizeof(SHFILEINFO),  SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
//  m_iIconProperty = sfi3.iIcon;

//  HICON   hIcon;   
//  hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDB);   

/*  Cil1.Create(IDB_VSICON, 16, 1, RGB(255, 0, 255)); // 建立16 位图像控制*/

    m_imageList.Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 10, 10);
    CBitmap bitmap;
    bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_VSICON);
    m_imageList.Add(&bitmap, RGB(255, 0, 255));

//  int bbb = Cil1.Add(aaa.FromHandle((HBITMAP) aaa), RGB(0, 0, 0));
    //Cil1.Add(LoadIcon(NULL, (LPCTSTR) IDR_AffensicsTYPE));// 增加选中状态图像

    m_wndTree.SetImageList(&m_imageList, TVSIL_NORMAL); //LVSIL_SMALL
    m_iIconFolderClosed = LIST_ICON_FOLDER_CLOSED;
    m_iIconScript = LIST_ICON_SCRIPT;
    m_iIconProperty = LIST_ICON_PROPERTY;

// 
//  HTREEITEM root = m_wndTree.InsertItem(_T("root"), 0, 0);
//  int i,j;
//  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
//  {
//      HTREEITEM item = m_wndTree.InsertItem(_T("item"), 1, 1,root);
//      for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
//      {
//          m_wndTree.InsertItem(_T("small"), 0, 1, item);
//      }
//  }
}

void CWorkSpaceBar2::add2Tree(CTreeCtrl* pTree, AFDir* pDir, HTREEITEM hItemParent, bool bHead)
{
    HTREEITEM hItem;

    int iIcon = pDir->is_dir? m_iIconFolderClosed : m_iIconScript;

    if (bHead)
    {
        hItem = pTree->InsertItem(pDir->name, iIcon, iIcon, TVI_ROOT);
        m_mapDirs[hItem] = pDir;
        m_mapDirs_R[pDir] = hItem;
    }
    else
    {
        hItem = pTree->InsertItem(pDir->name, iIcon, iIcon, hItemParent);
        m_mapDirs[hItem] = pDir;
        m_mapDirs_R[pDir] = hItem;
    }

    if (pDir->is_dir == TRUE)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < pDir->dirs.size(); i ++)
        {
            add2Tree(pTree, pDir->dirs[i], hItem, FALSE);
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < pDir->files.size(); i ++)
        {
            add2Tree(pTree, pDir->files[i], hItem, FALSE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        addScript2Tree(pTree, pDir, hItem);
    }
}

void CWorkSpaceBar2::OnSelchanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{

    *pResult = 0;
    return;
}
```

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Where are the unrelated items placed? May be they overlap a bit over the tree control due to which they are re-painted again. We you doing any UI update on click of the item?

Comment: The unrelated items is also the normal items inserted by the add2Tree() function in this CTreeList control, so there's no overlap. And I didn't do anything in the OnSelchanged() function.

Comment: It seems like a bug in CTreeCtrl, because I found that many basic CTreeCtrl source codes in the Internet also have the same problem. You can try the link I provided in the thread. This is a demo I found the flicker problem

Comment: I really do not understand your problem. sample  you are pointing to is hard to download, you have toi register on ill designed page. Once you manage to download, it turns that the project is created using ancient version of Visual studio (presumably 4.2) and once you upgrade it to the newer version it does not flicker at all.
Post your project (or create a test project that duplicates this problem) if you really want your problem resolved.